# Stuck: My own vesion for generating permutation

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to write my own code for generating permutation of items represented by numbers. Say 4 items can be represented by 0,1,2,3

I've seen the code from itertools product. That code is pretty neat. My way of coding this is using binary or ternary,... My code below only works for bits of less than 10. Part of this code split the str using list(s). Number 120 in base 11 is 1010, splitting '1010' yields, 1,0,1,0. For it to work correctly, I need to to split to 10, 10. Is there a way around this and still work with the rest of the code? 
Alternatively, what is a recursive version for this?  Thanks

```
aSet = 11
subSet = 2
s = ''
l = []
number = aSet**subSet

#finding all permutation, repeats allowed
for num in range(number):
    s = ''
    while num//aSet != 0:
        s = str(num%aSet) + s
        num = num//aSet
    else:
        s = str(num%aSet) + s 
    s = s.zfill(subSet)
    l.append(list(s))
```

Comment: What?  Your code doesn't use `str.split` anywhere.

Comment: sorry, i meant list(s), splitting the string into numbers.

Comment: Trincot's code is pretty good. I know there has to be recursive solution not using my logic with bits above. Recursion can be mind numbing a lot of times. I was trying to come up with a recursive solution but don't know where to start.. There are other recursive solutions but i have not seen one that deals with subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the problem with using a string, is that `list(s)` will chop it into individual characters. You should not create a string at all, but use a list for *s* from the start:

```
aSet = 11
subSet = 2
l = []
number = aSet**subSet

#finding all permutation, repeats allowed
for num in range(number):
    s = []
    for _ in range(subSet):
        s.insert(0, num%aSet)
        num = num//aSet
    l.append(s)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is great. I am a beginner. But it is pretty amazing that that there are people like you who can see with clarity when it comes to coding.